# Is it ok to wear a thong?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife, clothing

I just wear it for my husband so that he can have something to look at. Like is it permissible to wear it to impress him and make him (hard!). Can you give me reference to ahadiths and Qur'an as to what the wives of Rasoolullah Saw used to wear or do?

Comment: -1 Shows lack of research effort

Comment: If you are asking for wearing a thong only in front of your Husband, then what is the problem in wearing a thong in front a person, to which you can meet completely naked.

Answer (score 5):

A wife is strongly encouraged to dress in a way that pleases her husband sexually.  [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=253345) explains it's permissible in front of her husband:

> A woman is allowed to wear whatever clothes she wishes, even if tight, transparent, or revealing, and there is no harm in that as long as such clothes are worn in front of her husband only and it is not permissible for her to wear such clothes in front of anyone else.

It's not appropriate to disclose what happens in private between husband and wife:

> The most wicked among the people in the eye of Allah on the Day of judgment is the men who goes to his wife and she comes to him, and then he divulges her secret. -- [Sahih Muslim 1437](https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/144-145)

So we can expect there is little available information how the wives of the companions of the Prophet dressed to please their husbands (and therefore few hadith on the topic).  I only found a hadith relating to perfume:

> ...when she is with her husband, she may use any perfume she wishes... -- [Sunan Abi Dawud 4048](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/34/29) [grade: sahih]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can wear thong or any other cloth's to impress your husband.
But it's haram if you wear this for impress or attract other men's (who isn't your husband)